# How to Fix: ImportError: cannot import name 'dlldeps' from 'utils'

Tags: python, python-3.x

the problem is as described in the title.

I am trying to run the python script from
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/seungha.yang/gst-uwp-example/-/blob/master/update-vcxproj-assets.py which is using some utils package. I cant even figure out which package it should be, because the classes the script tries to import from it (dlldeps, gstprefix, vs) dont lead to any results when I google them.

Of course I tried to install, and reinstall and updated all the packages that could cause the error.

I am using Windows 10 and python 3.9 (downgraded from 3.11 since I tried to use 2to3 which apparently does not work with v 3.10+, but that also did not work).

I also tried to run it ob ubuntu 22.04 but I got the same error.

I suppose I am probably calling a wrong utils package? But I cant find the correct one and wouldn't know how to look for it.

The full traceback message goes:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\UP\mrayGStreamerUnity-master\Plugin\VS\update-vcxproj-assets.py", line 21, in <module> from utils import dlldeps ImportError: cannot import name 'dlldeps' from 'utils' (C:\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)`

I generated a requirements.txt file with the pipreqs package, which gave me the following output:

```
pefile==2023.2.7
utils==1.0.1
```

But pip list is showing that I have both installed with the correct version.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback mesage.

Comment: sure @JohnGordon '''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\UP\mrayGStreamerUnity-master\Plugin\VS\update-vcxproj-assets.py", line 21, in <module>
    from utils import dlldeps
ImportError: cannot import name 'dlldeps' from 'utils' (C:\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)'''

Comment: It appears that access to https://gitlab.freedesktop.org is blocked.

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify. Code and traces are hard to read in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: @StephenC Ok, that is new. It used to be accessible for a long time, but I think that has nothing to do with the problem. Should I post the content of the script in my question? It is about 60 lines long.

Comment: Maybe the `requirements.txt`file ... or whatever ... would be more helpful to work out where that "utils" module comes from.

Comment: @StephenC I updated my question according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. The url is not blocked anymore. When I downloaded and extracted the repo as a zip the folder gst-dll-tools was empty, but online it contains the missing .py files which I had to manually add to the C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\utils folder.